# Destructuring the API https://randomuser.me/api/ to grab title, last name, and first name also large photo of the user profile returned by the API

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm trying to grab some data(title, last name, first name and also large photo of the user profile returned by the API.) from the API https://randomuser.me/api/, which seem to not be working.

```
const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
    if(!data) return;

    // add your code here

    let {results} = data;

    let [profile] = results;

    document.querySelector('h2').textContent = profile.name.title +' '+ profile.name.last +' '+ profile.name.first;

    document.querySelector('img').src = profile.picture.large;


    displayExtraUserInfo(profile);
    clearNotice();
  };

  const getAUserProfile = () => {
    const api = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

    // make API call here

    fetch(api)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(data => {displayUserPhotoAndName()});

    notify(`requesting profile data ...`);
  };



  const displayBirthdate = ({dob = 'dob'}) => {
    document.querySelector('.details').textContent = dob.age;
  }

  const displayPhone = ({phone = 'phone', cell = 'cell'}) => {
    document.querySelector('.details').textContent = phone + ', ' + cell;
  }

  const displayAddress = ({location = 'location'}) => {
    document.querySelector('.details').textContent = location.street + ', ' + location.city + ', ' + location.state;
  }
```

Comment: You're not passing `data` to your function `.then(data => {displayUserPhotoAndName()});`. Make it `.then(data => {displayUserPhotoAndName(data)});`

Comment: But now i'm getting "Your displayBirthdate function is not displaying the specified user age returned by the API". Can you help me spot the error in my code?

Comment: "*seem to not be working*" - please be more specific. What doesn't work? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `data` to the function.Do like below

```
const getAUserProfile = () => {
    const api = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

    // make API call here

    fetch(api)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(data => {displayUserPhotoAndName(data)});  //this line is changed

    notify(`requesting profile data ...`);
};
```

Here is the line that will get all the required properties

```
let {results:[{ name: { title , first , last } , picture:{ large } }]} = data;
```

Comment: The first section of your correction, solved the problem, but now i'm getting "Your displayBirthdate function is not displaying the specified user age returned by the API". Can you help me spot the error in my code?

Comment: @Tochukwu You need to add the second line where you want to destructure the values as you mentioned above. Where did you put that line?And make sure to change `obj` in my answer with `data`.

Comment: @Tochukwu Also make sure to change `profile.name.title` with `title`  and other 3 like that

Comment: Thanks alot... I'm through. The first part served me already. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it and also handle bad data with default values. Also, do not forget to pass `data` to your function in the `then` callback:

```js
const display = data => {
  const { results: [{ name: { title, first, last } = {}, picture: { large } = {} }] = [] } = data || {};

  console.log(title, first, last, large);
};

fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/').then(r => display(r.json()));
```